# Track if the user logged in an account

Tags: asp.net, session

I need to create a session just like in php. we all know that the php has a session that is needed when you want to redirection on the web page using only the address bar, this is possible if the user has logged in an account. but if the user is not logged in and redirect to other page. that is impossible because of the session..

I am beginner in web development so please do understand me.

How can i do this in web application in visual studio.

Comment: just implement a cookie-based authentication mechanism using `Asp.Net Identity`

Comment: @Aarif how to do that sir? I am new on developing a web app.. Actually, this is my first time developing a web based project. and i dont really have any idea on how to implement those things.

Comment: here are some recommended resources by `Microsoft`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources

Comment: You can use `Session` to track down a user session.You would explicitly need to define your session variables and their usage throughout your application. There are good mechanisms in .NET that provide you with this functionality.